# Android Studio - NoClassDefFoundError when using a JAR dependency (a libGDX project)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

So, I've coded a plain Java project that I'd like to use in my Android project. The project to be imported was written in Eclipse, so I've exported it as a (runnable) JAR file and added it to the dependencies of my project. However, the program fails when I try to run it with this message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 20499
Process: com.mkcode.droidrogue, PID: 29039
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mkcode/dmg/Generator;
```

I'm new to Android Studio. I know that in Eclipse I could edit the project's run configuration and add the JAR there, but I haven't found anything like that in Android Studio. I've added the JAR as both a compile-time and runtime dependency like this:

[image: project dependencies]

The project is a libGDX project divided into sub-projects (core, Android, iOS, desktop). Every launcher project includes the core project into itself.

What could I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, I added the following to the `build.gradle` file of the root project:

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        ...
        compile files('libs/DungeonMapGenerator.jar') // ADDED THIS LINE
    }
```

}